# SharePoint 2013 run both Continues and Incremental Crawl

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawling

As per the MSDN article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802(v=office.15).aspx

> A continuous crawl does not process or retry items that return errors more than three times. A "clean-up" incremental crawl automatically runs every four hours for content sources that have continuous crawl enabled to re-crawl any items that repeatedly return errors. This incremental crawl will try to crawl the item again and then will postpone retries if the error persists.

But can I schedule the incremental crawl to run every 30 minutes apart from running the continues crawl? In the SharePoint admin screen, I can either either schedule the incremental or continues crawl but not both.

Can I do this using a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the interval for Full and Incremental crawls on the admin screen. The only way to change continuous crawl duration is with powershell below:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SetProperty("ContinuousCrawlInterval",n)
```

where `n` is the regular interval in minutes at which you want to continuous crawls to start.